# same URL to trigger HTTP Post and HTTP Delete verbs in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have scenario where I want to trigger HTTPDelete or HTTPPost verbs with the same URL.
Eg. url  = https://localHost:12345/api/home/1234/Products
has to trigger following methods

```
    [Route("api/home/{id}/Products")]
    [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult DeleteProducts(string id)
    {
       /* Some Business logic*/
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    [Route("api/home/{id}/Products")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddProducts(string id)
    {
       /* Some Business logic*/
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

How to achieve it in MVC .Net4 framework.

Comment: Does it have to be done via the URL or can you just call the other method from your controller?

Comment: It call via URL.

Comment: I'm guessing you're wanting to call the AddProducts action after calling the DeleteProducts action?

Comment: well not exactly. it could be any way.